# What is the max number of access tokens one can generate with Square?

Tags: access-token, square

https://github.com/square/connect-javascript-sdk/blob/master/docs/OAuthApi.md#obtainToken

How many access tokens can be generated per personal API token with Square SDK? A million at a time? Infinite? 100? It doesn't mention on the website, nor on any other Stripe documentation that I could find.

Comment: You mention Stripe in the question, but that link is to a Square library :) Which do you mean?

Comment: Fixed, thanks for the comment. Too many Payments services..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really mean Square, and you're solely talking about OAuthing other merchants (based on the link you provided) then our docs say:

> By default, the OAuth API lets up to 500 Square accounts authorize your application.

It is possible to increase that number, but you would need to reach out to support and communicate the need with them.

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/oauth#navsection-oauth